# “The system is running in low-graphics mode” - internet not working in recovery

Tags: graphics, xorg, lightdm, login-screen, amd-graphics

All the solutions to [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) require for you to have internet.

I only have wireless internet and when I am in that console the internet is not connected so I cannot install, update or reinstall anything.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have the HP Pavilion 17-e020sq laptop (which has an intel graphics and a dedicated ATI one).

I checked how to connect to wifi from terminal but it seems I need to install a bunch of stuff to be able to do that!

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you installed the `xserver-xorg-video-ati` driver package?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks guys! What I did was to go to recovery mode, enable networking, press yes, the terminal appears on the bottom half of the screen, I pressed ctrl + C then after a few seconds the desktop appears... the first thing I do is to install the ati driver, restart, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix it was

- go to *recovery mode*
- select enable networking
- press *yes* - the terminal appears on the bottom half of the screen
- I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then after a few seconds the desktop appears... the first thing I do is to install the ati driver, restart, and now it works!